# Hacer group by para obtener el valor máximo de una lista

Tags: c#, linq

Cordial saludo. En la actualidad estoy intentando obtener el registro mas reciente de una base de datos. Ya lo tengo realizado en SQL Server pero no he podido hacerlo en c#.
Esta es la consulta que ya me funciona en SQL server:

```
select id,
       Max(Registro) as ValorMaximo
from LlanHistoria
Where id = '106534'
group by id
```

Esta es la consulta que estoy desarrollando en c#

```
var q = from a in context.LlanHistoria
                where
                    a.id == "106534"
                group a by a.id into GrupoA
                select new
                {
                    GrupoA.Key,
                    GrupoA.Max()
                };
```

Me sale el siguiente error:

```
Error CS0746: Invalide anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.
```

Agradezco sus recomendaciones para identificar mi error y poder lograr que funcione el codigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var lista = from a in context.LlanHistoria
            where a.id == "106534"
            group a by a.id into GrupoA
            select new
            {
                Id = GrupoA.Key,
                Mayor = GrupoA.Max(a => a.Registro)
            };
```

El error está dado porque debes darle un nombre a las propiedades del **objeto anónimo** que estás creando, en este caso yo le doy los nombres **Id** y **Mayor**, por otra parte para obtener el mayor registro de cada grupo hago uso del **método Max** teniendo en cuenta la **propiedad Registro**.

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas realizar un `group by` en linq para obtener el máximo, simplemente obtén los registros requeridos usando un `Where` y a esos registros le pides el máximo utilizando `Max`

```
var q =  context.LlanHistoria.Where(a=>a.id == "106534").Max(a=>a.Registro);
```

Comment: Yo pensé en esto pero después me di cuenta que el usuario quería saber según lo que tenía hecho cual era su error y respondí atendiendo a la propia respuesta del usuario, igual tú respuesta es correcta y le enseña una vía más fácil de obtener lo que pide